# When "all" is used with personal pronouns? What exactly is it?

Tags: grammar, personal-pronouns

As you know, **all** can be used with personal pronouns, right?
I want to know what exactly it is; an adverb or something else?

Two examples:

> They've eaten it all.
>   All it takes is 5 minutes to rock the cloud.

Comment: It's a determiner: see here for more information:  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/all

Comment: @Man_From_India : i think in my last sentence it's not a determiner because after it's "it" a Subject pronouns, not a noun .

Comment: @hoangtu9x sorry my last comment contained mistakes.

Comment: In your last sentence **all** is a determiner. It is used in your last sentence as a fused determiner phrase.  In case of your first example, **all** is a modifier, and it modifies **it**. The traditional grammar, however, will explain it a different way. According to them In both of your cited sentences **all** is a pronoun.

Answer (score 2):

*'All'* can be a determiner, a predeterminer, a pronoun or an adverb.

For each I'll give an example.

Determiner:

> The boys played video games all
>   day.

Predeterminer:

> Have you done all your homework?

Pronoun:

> All you need is a hammer and some nails.

Adverb:

> He got all wet.

1. They've eaten it all.

In your first example 'all' is used after the object pronoun for emphasis which is a ***determiner*** here the other way of saying this is *'all of it'*.

I quote this part from  *Cambridge Dictionaries Online* at http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/all

> When all refers to a personal pronoun which is the object in a clause, we can use pronoun + all or all of + pronoun. The pronoun is in the object form:
>
> I used to have three pens but I’ve lost them all. (or … but I’ve lost all of them).
>
> Not: … but I lost all them.
>
> However, in short responses, all of must be used:
>
> A: How many of these boxes are you going to need?
>
> B: All of them.
>
> Not: Them all. ×

2. All it takes is 5 minutes to rock the cloud.

In the second example of yours it's a ***pronoun*** which means *'everything'* or here to customize the definition I'd go with *'the only thing'*.

Comment: Just one point i don't really understand in my first sentence "They've eaten it all" is Why determiner is after a pronoun . Usually, determiner is before pronoun , right ? Or in this case that pronoun is in object form ?

Comment: Yea right but in the link that I put in my answer you'll see this structure has been classified as a determiner. Actually this 'object pronoun + all' falls under 'all as a determiner' category.

Comment: However, I personally think 'all' is not a determiner and more of a 'quantifier' here.

Comment: Visit my link :http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/all_2 it's from Oxford . It say "all" is a pronoun in my first sentence "They've eaten it all" .And now after a object can be a pronoun ? It make me confuse .

Comment: You'd be probably surprised if you chech this link on Merriam Webster dictionary that considers 'all' as an adjective, too. I think it's probably the difference that exist between dictionaries. What I said was based on Cambriedge Dictionaries online. Not sure really which one is correct.  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all

Answer (score 0):

"all of you/ you ...all" means the total number of you, without exception. 
"all of it/it all" as in "The dog has eaten all of the cake/all of it" means the whole cake. This indication of how many/how much is in traditional grammar called an indefinite numeral.

Answer (score 0):

After researching more detail, i found what the grammar point in my first example sentence "They've eaten it all" is . It's totally a adverb . Just see this sentence "i eat it quickly " . And "all" in this case is the same .who agree with me ?

Comment: I don't. If it's an adverb, what does it modify? The sentence you mentioned is different from what OP quoted, even surface structure is not similar.